# Very slow reboot on Windows 10. Stuck on black "windows screen" for about minute and a half. Boot and shutdown are fine

Tags: windows-10, boot, reboot

for months now restarting is slow on my PC, I have SSD and booting is fine. Shutdown is fine, also hibernating, sleeping.
Only restarting is problem since it needs almost a minute and a half, maybe more.

I have SSD and two HDD (one is much older, from my older PC), tried to disconnect the old one, nothing. Also tried to disconnect my external HDD from USB, also nothing.

Then I installed WPT, since I don't know what to try anymore.

Here's the link for .etl file, hope someone can help me:[GDrive link (130MB)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7UHUUuixOAQV1l3S3dYdDhpSDQ)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user asks for support of a pirated Windows 10. Such questions should be closed

Comment: I disagree. How can a W10 be pirated if you can use it indefinitely by default without a license ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no delay. Boot is done in 12.5 seconds. Postboot (startup of all tools at logon takes a lot of time).

[image]

I see `sppsvc.exe` causes some CPU usage for 30s, this is likely caused by using your KMS crack (`C:\Windows\KMS-R@1n.exe`) to activate Windows 10 Pro.

[image]

So, remove the crack and buy a legal license.

Comment: thanks, but why is booting working fine? this happens only when restarting. and ofc I would like to have a legal licence, but it's not that easy when you are living in a country where average salary is a little over 300e

Comment: sorry, no support for pirated Windows here. if you have a genuine Win7 key, you can still use the win7 key to activate win10.